# Fixing duplicate without user-selected canonical in Blogger

Tags: canonical-url, blogger, rel-canonical, google-selected-canonical

I recently started blogging through blogger. On my Google Search Console account, I got the error  "Duplicate without user-selected canonical" error. When I inspected the affected pages I saw:

```
?m=1
```

at the end of the affected URLs. I saw a fix online and added the following line in the HTML of my Blogger account:

```
<link expr:href='data:blog.url' rel='canonical'/>
```

I also saw a similar line to the one above which is as follows:

```
<link expr:href='data:blog.url.canonical' rel= 'canonical'/>
```

I wanted to ask that is there a difference between these two lines of code. Which one is the correct line?
Also if the original URL without **?m=1** is indexed and the URL with **?m=1** is not indexed should I leave it like this or do I need to enter one of the above line in the HTML code of my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An **URL** with a parameter is a different URL as compared to one without a parameter.  If they both serve the same page then you have a duplicate page.  The fix is to put a canonical tag with the preferred URL in it.

> **What is a canonical URL?**
>
> A canonical URL is the URL of the page that Google thinks is most representative from a set of duplicate pages on your site. For example, if you have URLs for the same page (`example.com?dress=1234` and `example.com/dresses/1234`), Google chooses one as canonical.

From [developers.google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/consolidate-duplicate-urls)

---

`<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com">` or

`<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com">`

are the normal way to specify a canonical, depending on whether you are supporting **www**.  But it is advisable to put in a complete (absolute) Link.  If you do not do that then you can still have duplication because of **http**/**https** protocol and **www**/**non www** preferences.

Comment: can you write the complete code with the link?

Comment: Updated the answer.  Please remember that you can also contribute to this community that helps you. As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, accept it and even upvote it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Did the answer work for you ?